# Button that loads the default camera app, but doesn't expect any return value or input

Tags: javascript, html

I built a series of pages for a QR code scavenger hunt. I would love to include a button at the bottom that returns them to their camera app to scan and visit another page. All I could find, was where people use HTML5 to upload a photo using the following:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

This does indeed fire up the camera, but tries to send any photo taken back to the page. Is there any way to just load up the app? I don't need any return data at all.

I have tried doing something like:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnTest" capture="camera">Camera</button>
```

but no luck. Any advice? Ideally I would like something that would work for Android and iOS.

Thank you!

Comment: a web page doesn't have permission to directly open apps on a user's device.

Comment: Bummer. How does the <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"> work so effectively then? At least on my test android device, it prompts for which camera to open.

Comment: yes because that's done through a defined API where the user must interact with your page and give consent before it can access the camera. And even then it only has the ability really to do one simple job - capture an image and load the data into your `<input` field in the page. It can't then go off and do other arbitrary tasks in your device. There's no API for doing things like opening other apps (not least because, not all devices are the same and opening an app is O/S specific, and also because A.N Other app could easily be malicious.)

Comment: For instance there is the media devices API (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices for info), or the Navigator API which lets you do things like request the user's location (which might be based on the GPS on their device, and/or other factors if they don't have GPS) - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator . There are a number of these pre-defined APIs which scope what interactions your browser can (safely) have with the device.